# Using Nginx as a reverse proxy for node servers

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I've read several articles ([here](https://m.alphasights.com/using-nginx-on-heroku-to-serve-single-page-apps-and-avoid-cors-5d013b171a45)) ([and here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/5-performance-tips-for-node-js-applications/)) discussion how to properly configure Nginx as a reverse proxy server for node back-end servers (micro service architecture) and they all highlight the following key benefits:

- Efficiently serve static content
- Avoid CORS requests
- Managing Load Balancing
- Mitigate DDoS attacks

I understand all but the last benefit, Mitigate DDoS attacks. How does ngnix help with this. Doesn't the node api still have to be public facing? For example if we had a proxy configuration like the following:

```
"proxies": {
"/api/": {
  "origin": "https://backend.example.com/api"
  }
}
```

Isn't https://backend.example.com/api still suseptible to DDoS attacks? If someone could elborate on this it would be helpful.

Comment: [Mitigating DDoS Attacks with NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/)

Comment: For example Nginx helps caching data returned by Node server (google `nginx proxy_cache`), and can limit connections frequency by IP/subnet per second/minute/etc.